# Naming compound with multiple carbonyl and/or hydroxyl groups

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, carbonyl-compounds

I think I understood the main idea behind naming compounds with carbonyl groups, however I am not sure about a few things.

[image: Compounds]

For the first compound, there is more than one carbonyl group and one of them is in the end of the chain. I am trying to decide between *2-oxopropanal* and *propana-1,2-dione*.

For the second one, I am not sure what happens if there are two oxygens attached to a carbon atom with a double bond. I am trying to decide between *methanedione* and *methanedial*.

I am not sure about this because one definition of aldehydes I have heard is when the carbon atom is attached to a hydrogen as well as the oxygen. And the other is if it is in the end of the chain.

And the final compound that I am not sure about is when there are two hydroxyl groups attached to the carbon as well as an oxygen with a double bond. I think it is *hydroxymethanoic acid*, but I am not completely sure.

Comment: The second compound is carbon dioxide anyway, the first one is 2-oxopropanal because it doesn't have 2 ketones and number 3 is carbonic acid

Comment: but hydroxymethanoic acid is also correct

Comment: @MrLuke370 Yeah, many names are correct. However, I am looking for the IUPAC preferred names.

Comment: Why don't you try chemspider to see what options it gives?

Comment: @MrLuke370I had never heard of it before, but there doesn't seem to be an option to name it. It just gives me a list of compounds that match mine and they have names but they are not the systematic names.

Comment: In the name sectionin light grey it says IUPAC beside the correct names, and I also put those compounds through chemdraw and it gave the names in my first comment, and as far as i know chemdraw gives IUPAC names .However I could stand to be corrected on that last point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Carbon dioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide) and [carbonic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonic_acid) are **inorganic** compounds, and therefore would not be named using the IUPAC nomenclature for **organic** compounds.

The other compound is named 2-oxopropanal, because aldehydes have higher priority than ketones by [IUPAC rules](https://www.angelo.edu/faculty/kboudrea/organic/IUPAC_Handout.pdf).

Comment: And why are they considered inorganic when they contain carbon in its excited state? What are the criteria for deciding if a compound is organic or not?

Comment: [It's complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_compound#Modern_classification), but generally speaking, $\ce{C-H}$ bonds.

Comment: What is "carbon in its excited state"... there is no such thing.